# Cache backend configuration

Tags: caching

I'm trying to use filecache and authcache and I'm running into the same issue with both.  The documentation says I only need to add an entry to $conf['cache_backends'] and then define what that cache type should be used for.

This never works for me and I'm curious if it supposed to and I'm missing a step.  The only way I've gotten this to work properly is to manually include the file that defines the cache class.

UPDATE: it works if I put the includes at the top of my settings.php file, but not the bottom.  This doesn't make sense to me.